# 'Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root1' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root1'@'localho

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Please I really need some help here. I am trying to make a connection to my SQL database on Visual Studio but i keep getting the error below;

> `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root1' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'` **

My connectiion string code is seen below

```
    Dim sqlConn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user=root1; password=adimuser; database=access_table")

    Dim sqlCmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim sqlRd As MySqlDataReader
    Dim sqlDT As New DataTable
    Dim sqlAdapt As New MySqlDataAdapter 
   
    Private bitmap As Bitmap
   
    Private Sub updateTable()
        
        sqlConn.Open()
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn REM This is to connect to the connection string of SQLCONN
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From access_control.accesstable"

        sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader

        sqlDT.Load(sqlRd) REM Load whatever is read from the reader into the database
        sqlRd.Close()
        sqlConn.Close()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = sqlDT

    End Sub
```

Been getting the same error

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html

Comment: @user9938 thank you for the info still came in useful but i was able to figure it out.

Comment: Not to be rude, but the error to me seems pretty clear.  You're simply using the wrong credentials.  Other than advise on the connection string, not sure anyone here is going to be able to help much as this is an environment issue